# I think we need an ability to subscribe to a question

Tags: feature-request, notifications

Right now when i see a question that needs more details, i ask the OP about adding some more details to the question, and he will probably add some extra details and then respond to me using @ in the comments.

But when a question actually needs more information, but someone already asked for that (such as [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/267393/how-to-load-this-code-on-function-php) one) , i can't leave another comment with the exact note. It is annoying for the OP, and there is a chance he will not reply to the next comment.

So i have to either bookmark/favorite the question or remember the title to check it later to see if the required information have been added to it or not (since i can't answer the question without further information).

What i'm thinking is, there should actually be a subscribe button for each question so we can receive notifications about that.

There is actually an RSS feed available right now, but not very satisfying. A user friendly feature like this in WPSE would be nicer. What do you think?

**PS :** I couldn't find another topic about this, and haven't notice any feature like this in my 11 months membership. so excuse me if this is a repetitive question on meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [userscript for the Stack Exchange websites](https://github.com/soscripted/sox) that adds that feature:

> [image]

It has a lot of additional options, and in my experience also some bugs … but I think it's worth a try.

A workaround without extra tools is the *Favorite* feature: If you favorite a question, you can sort these in your profile by last activity. But that requires a manual check. Not very convenient in my experience.

Comment: Thank you i will try. However a feature that would be more user friendly could come in handy, especially that not everyone knows about this ( i didn't myself), particularly the new users.

Comment: @JackJohansson I have added a workaround to my answer.

Comment: Yes, i mentioned that in my question. I don't think it takes a lot of effort to make this happen right? I mean it's basically the same as when someone responds to you using @, with the difference that it shows a notification for every activity on that post.

Comment: @JackJohansson We don't make any of the functionality here. That's the overall Stack Exchange functionality. You may want to search and ( if not found ) bring it up on [Meta Stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) where features may actually be implemented.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Thanks for your comments. I noticed there is a `feature-request` tag so i posted this question. By the way, i think moderators and older users like you are closer to the development team, so they might have a better chance of discussing the matter if they had some time.